# Variables are not expanded in smb.conf when using Samba 4

Tags: active-directory, samba, winbind, samba4

I'm using Samba 4.0.0beta2 on Debian Wheezy as Active Directory domain controller. I also use winbind in my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` so `getent passwd` returns domain users.

I've set

```
template homedir = /home/%U
```

in my `smb.conf` file but, instead of substituting `%U` for username, `getent passwd` returns:

```
HOME\Administrator:*:0:100::/home/%U:/bin/bash
HOME\Guest:*:3000000:3000001::/home/%U:/bin/bash
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The value has change since Samba4,

New value for the username is %ACCOUNTNAME% use as this :

```
template homedir = /home/%ACCOUNTNAME%
```

Comment: I wrote a [similar QA](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156449/9259) on the Unix and Linux site: